# Array AND() ? Logical ANDing of all elements

Tags: php, arrays, boolean-logic

I have an array and I want to find out if there is at least one false value in it. I was thinking of creating an `array_and()` function, that just performs a logical AND on all the elements. It would return true if all values are true, otherwise false. Am I over-engineering?

Comment: That's a perfectly valid operation to do, and if PHP doesn't have it built-in, you can easily do it with `array_reduce` (or `fold`, as this higher-order function is more commonly called).

Comment: @delnan: This requires iteration over the entire array, however, regardless of whether it even contains a `true`, let alone whether a `false` is encountered before the end of the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why dont you just use

- [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.in-array.php) — Checks if a value exists in an array

Example:

```
// creates an array with 10 booleans having the value true.
$array = array_fill(0, 10, TRUE);

// checking if it contains a boolean false
var_dump(in_array(FALSE, $array, TRUE)); // FALSE

// adding a boolean with the value false to the array
$array[] = FALSE;

// checking if it contains a boolean false now
var_dump(in_array(FALSE, $array, TRUE)); // TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was thinking too much :)

Comment: @user just to clarify: by "false value" you actually mean you want to check if there a *boolean false* in the array, right?

Comment: Yeah, this happens to be a situation where it would be boolean `FALSE`, but is this generalizable to PHP's loose type checking? For loose type checking, I would have to use a function, no?

Comment: @user no, you just have to use the third argument `bool $strict`. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 5):

> It would return true if all values are true, otherwise false.

Returns true if array is non empty and contains no false elements:

```
function array_and(arary $arr)
{
  return $arr && array_reduce($arr, function($a, $b) { return $a && $b; }, true));
}
```

(Note that you would need strict comparison if you wanted to test against the `false` type.)

> Am I over-engineering?

Yes, because you could use:

```
in_array(false, $arr, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this in principle, as long as you don't AND all of the values indiscriminately; that is, you should terminate as soon as the first `false` is found:

```
function array_and(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        if (!$value)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to implement a small function that takes an array and iterates over it checking each member to see if it is false. Return a bool from the function based on the outcome of your checking....

Answer (score 0):

Easy but ugly => O(N)

```
$a = array(1, 2, false, 5, 6, 'a');

$_there_is_a_false = false
foreach ($a as $b) {
    $_there_is_a_false = !$b ? true : $_there_is_a_false;
}
```

another option: [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use array_product()

> $set = array(1,1,1,1,0,0);
>
> $result = array_product($set);
>
> Output: 0

AND Logical is essentially a multiplier.

1 * 1 = 1

1 * 0 = 0

0 * 1 = 0

0 * 0 = 0